# VBA macro to find one column value to other column in different sheet

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I need a formula that will match patient name from sheet 2 in sheet 1, then see if column H in that row has 'Yes' written in it and if so, change color of that row in sheet 2 to red.

I have written this formula -

```
Dim patient1 As String
Dim patient2 As String
Dim answer As String
Dim c As Range
Dim counter As Long
Dim total As Long
counter = 1
total = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To total
answer = Worksheets("hedis1").Range("h" & counter).Value
patient1 = Worksheets("hedis1").Range("d" & counter).Value
patient2 = Worksheets("hedis2").Range("d" & counter).Value
k = "a" & counter
If patient1 = patient2 Then
   If answer = "Yes" Then
        For Each c In Worksheets("hedis2").Range(k)

            c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 255 ' Change the number to match the desired color.

        Next c
   End If
End If
counter = counter + 1
Next i
```

I want to check all values of column D of spreadsheet1 to column D of spreadsheet2. My formula checks only for same rows.
Hope you understand what I am trying to say.
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered doing this with Conditional Formatting? That would eliminate the need for VBA.

Comment: @DougGlancy How can I do this task with conditional formatting? By the way I want this to be done thru VBA. Thanks

Comment: If you need to use VBA then my comment is unhelpful. If you're interested in how to use CF there's lots of great information on the web.

Comment: @DougGlancy I want it in VBA because it is just one condition. I have to use it in other conditions also which are complex and can't be possible thru CF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Worksheet match function, its very fast...

```
Dim patient1 As String
Dim answer As String
Dim total As Long
Dim iRowMatched As Long

total = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

On Error Resume Next
For i = 1 To total
    answer = Worksheets("hedis1").Range("h" & counter).Value
    patient1 = Worksheets("hedis1").Range("d" & counter).Value

    iRowMatched = WorkSheetFunction.Match(patient1,Worksheets("hedis1").Range("$D:$D"),0)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
           If answer = "Yes" Then
                Worksheets("hedis2").Rows(iRowMatched).Interior.Color = vbRed '
           End If
    Else
       Err.Clear
    End If
Next i
On Error Goto 0
```

Comment: I tried your code. It is working after few changes but these were not your part. You showed the concept and it works. Thnx bro!!!

Comment: Nice, i coded that in my iPhone, it would fail in some part. for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for you, not sure I'm 100% on what you want.

```
Sub thisone()
Dim patient1 As String
Dim patient2 As String
Dim answer As String
Dim c As Range
Dim counter As Long
Dim total As Long
Dim totalInner As Long
counter = 1
total = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
totalInner = Worksheets("hedis2").Range("d" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To total
answer = Worksheets("hedis1").Range("h" & counter).Value
patient1 = Worksheets("hedis1").Range("d" & counter).Value
k = "a" & counter
For j = 1 To totalInner
    patient2 = Worksheets("hedis2").Range("d" & j).Value

    If patient1 = patient2 Then
        If answer = "Yes" Then
            For Each c In Worksheets("hedis2").Range(k)

                c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 255 ' Change the number to match the desired color.

            Next c
        End If
    End If
    Next j
counter = counter + 1
Next i
End Sub
```